# How's robot vacuum cleaner back to charger when battery is low?

Tags: mobile-robot, control, localization, raspberry-pi

What's technology robot vacuum cleaner used to locate it's charger when battery is low ?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mostafa Albana, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that all robot vacuum cleaners use it, but the models that I have played with (the [Neato XV-15](http://www.trustedreviews.com/reviews/neato-xv-11) and [Xiaomi Mi](https://www.vacuumsguide.com/xiaomi-mi-robot-vacuum-cleaner/)) use variations of the Simultaneous Location and Mapping ([SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping)) algorithm.

Both robots use a LIDAR as the main navigation sensor for SLAM. There is a rather nice paper available on the [Characterization of the Neato LIDAR unit](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:995686/FULLTEXT01.pdf) if you would like more information.

In simple terms, the SLAM algorithm uses sensor data to create a map while the robot is cleaning. This allows it to plan a path from its current location back to the base station / charger at the end of the cleaning cycle, or when the battery charge drops below a predefined threshold.

If you are unfamiliar with SLAM, a good place to start is the [SLAM for Dummies](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-412j-cognitive-robotics-spring-2005/projects/1aslam_blas_repo.pdf) guide produced by Søren Riisgaard and Morten Rufus Blas at MIT.

Comment: That's kind of impressive. Did they use also an external sensor with SLAM? Some infrared sensors ? Or is that only for the docking ?

Comment: Gosh I gotta look at those vacuum cleaner again they got so much better than before :)! Still I would think docking in the station with just SLAM would be hard even with a lidar ( maybe drift, or just accuracy of the map). Is the version of slam they use available online ? I'm genuinely interested :)!

Comment: @Malcolm It probably is by now. I got my XV-15 second-hand for £20 a few years ago. Stripped it down & cleaned it & it worked perfectly. Then I bought the Xiaomi so I pulled the LIDAR out of the XV-15 to use in another robot. :)

Comment: That's one very cheap lidar, congrats :)! Did it work good on your other robot ? Is it 2D or 3D?

Comment: @Malcolm It worked fine. I've added some info about the LIDAR to my answer. :)

Comment: Awesome ! I'll read it as soon as I'm home next week :3! Thanks again !